# Remote MySQL service unreachable due to port 3306 being blocked locally

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, mysql, port

Here is the network setup:

- The computers (Windows PC, RPi,...) making the MySQL connection are located in a network that has blocked port 3306 in there firewall (among others).
- We do not have access to the firewall and cannot change it's configuration, neither does the owner of the firewall (don't ask me why...).
- Our database is hosted remotely and is only reachable on port 3306 (mysql.XXXXX.be:3306).
- We cannot change the DB configuration.

We tried with no success:

- Using ngrok on the computer opening the connection and opening a TCP tunnel to 3306, but this only opens the port locally.
- Using an SSH tunnel to the DB, but the DB does not seem to support SSH.

How can we reach the database? Are there online services that support some kind of port forwarding?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer, not possible. If you can't change the port and its blocked, then there simply is no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to not be possible.
However it seems we do have SSH on the DB server and we were able to connect to the DB using SSH Tunneling.